# Best way to update multiple attributes in nested state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, nested

Just before I go about having to learn Redux or use Immer, I was wondering if anyone knew of a simple way to do this. I checked the React docs but I must be making a mistake somewhere, and need new sets of eyes on this.

I've got a `users` array of objects that is set to state {i.e. `users, setUsers`) , where each `user` object that has nested within it `posts` and `concerts`. Here's an example of one of them:

```
{
        "id": 305,
        "username": "L0V3MUSIC",
        "email": "kanisha.hansen@bayer.co",
        "posts": [
          {
                "id": 129,
                "body": "PLEASE EMAIL IF YOU HAVE 4 TICKETS ALTOGETHER! MY DAUGHTERS LOVE HER -- THX ",
                "for_sale": false,
                "tickets": 4,
                "concert_id": 51,
                "user_id": 305
          }
        ],
        "concerts": [
            {
                "id": 51,
                "date": "2023-07-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                "location": "Brooklyn Steel",
                "image": "https://i.imgur.com/SmFrzTC.jpg",
                "artist_id": 37
                }
           ]
},
```

I've also got `concerts` state holding an array of objects  with the same information also and in the same way as above with users.

```
{
        "id": 51,
        "date": "2023-07-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "location": "Brooklyn Steel",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/SmFrzTC.jpg",
        "artist_id": 37,
        "artist": {
                    "id": 37,
                    "name": "Adele",
                    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/zmGbfKS.jpg",
                    "genre": "Pop"
                 },
        "posts": [
            {
                    "id": 123,
                    "body": "2 tickets, $100 total OBO -- CHEAPEST YOU'LL EVER FIND FOR ADELE!!",
                    "for_sale": true,
                    "tickets": 2,
                    "concert_id": 51,
                    "user_id": 289
            },
            {
                    "id": 124,
                    "body": "3 tickets, $400 total OBO!",
                    "for_sale": true,
                    "tickets": 3,
                    "concert_id": 51,
                    "user_id": 289
           },
           {
                    "id": 129,
                    "body": "PLEASE EMAIL IF YOU HAVE 4 TICKETS ALTOGETHER! MY DAUGHTERS LOVE HER -- THX ",
                    "for_sale": false,
                    "tickets": 4,
                    "concert_id": 51,
                    "user_id": 305
         }
   ],
        "users": [
           {
                    "id": 289,
                    "username": "onlineguy1",
                    "email": "su@cronin.name"
            },
            {
                    "id": 305,
                    "username": "L0V3MUSIC",
                    "email": "kanisha.hansen@bayer.co"


              }
             ]
   },
```

My issue is that I want to update a `post` that a `user` enters. I'd like to iterate either through `users` or through `concerts`, as I'm not sure which is best just yet given that both are 'symmetrical' in a sense. *I don't want to have a posts state object though as I'm being graded on my ability to access users through concerts, and concerts through users.*
`currentUser` is just the `user` that is currently logged in, and who would be the author of the created post. What I've tried to do a bunch of different ways is this: (here's my latest iteration)

```
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299) {
        response.json().then((createdPost) => {
          console.log('createdPost: ', createdPost);
          const updatedPosts = currentUser.posts.map((eachPost) => {
            if (eachPost.id === createdPost.id) {
              return createdPost;
            } else {
              return eachPost;
            }
          });
          console.log('updatedPosts: ', updatedPosts);
          setCurrentUser(...currentUser, currentUser.posts: updatedPosts)
          // FIGURE OUT HOW TO UPDATE THE STATE OF THE ABOVE 
          // THEN MAP THROUGH USERS AND UPDATE THAT USER WITH CURRENTUSER INSTEAD
        });
        setError([]);
        setSuccess('Your post has been created!');
        setSubmitted(true);
      } else {
```

What I have above is updating the `currentUser`'s posts and have an updated collection of the `currentUser`'s post, and then ideally update the users state itself with this `currentUser` (and his updated posts) replacing `currentUser` (and his now outdated posts, given that they don't include the newly created post). But I've managed to confuse myself through the nesting and mapping and staring at this too long.

Is there a concise way to go about either updating the posts altogether then iterating through the `user` then updating `users` state, in a way that doesn't require redux or a plugin? Or is there a better way to go about handling this entirely? I'm assuming for sure that I'm being sloppy in getting this done so I'll take any steps in the right direction